# website desktop shortcut with prefilled form

Tags: javascript, html, office365

I'm trying to make a desktop shortcut for a website (https://login.microsoftonline.com/login.srf). But I want to make an individual shortcut for each of my coworkers that automatically fills in their username.

Filling in the form would be easy enough to do with JS but is there a way i can add a layer of JS to a webpage?

I looked at bookmarklets but i don't think they allow to make a desktop shortcut.

Thanks!